# codeigniter - website url in query string gives not found error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am passing website url in query string but it is giving 404 page not found.I have checked permitted uri character is config and also checked htaccess but it is not working.

URI example is as follows:

```
https://www.example.com/dev/login/after_gmail_login?text=https://www.example2.com
```

**CONFIG**

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_,\-[]%+';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE; 
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c'; 
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm'; 
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd'; 
// experimental not currently in use route is :
$route['default_controller'] = "Login"; 
$route['404_override'] = ''; 
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Can you post your routes and config?

Comment: config is : 

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_,\-[]%+';   
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use

route is : 
$route['default_controller'] = "Login";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: Please add it inline in code to the original post :)